# Does "stoop" have a figurative meaning?

Tags: figurative-language

```
But you didn't have to cut me off
Make out like it never happened and that we were nothing
And I don't even need your love
But you treat me like a stranger, and that feels so rough
No, you didn't have to **stoop so low**
Have your friends collect your records and then change your number
I guess that I don't need that, though
Now you're just somebody that I used to know
```

In the above text, does "stoop" have a figurative meaning? The literal does not seem to make sense. Also, what does "records" mean in this context?

Comment: Is the person being addressed a musician whose recordings people used to collect? Discs were often called 'records'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lyrics are generally a poor source of idiomatic English.

There is an expression "to stoop low" which means "to drop your moral standards far enough to do something bad or unpleasant." (Cambridge) Presumably this is a use, or adaptation of this expression.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by a poor source? Do you mean  "to stoop low"  is not something you use normally or if I say it to some body they may not understand it?

Comment: I mean lyrics are not good examples of how English is spoken idiomatically.  They are good examples of how lyrics are written. If you are writing lyrics in English, then study lyrics.  If you want to communicate in prose then lyrics are not so useful.

Comment: Song writers often choose words to fit the rhyme or metre of the verse, not necessarily the words they would use when talking normally in prose. But the metaphorical use of [stoop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stoop-to) is quite common.

Comment: I regularly stoop quite low in order to tie my shoe laces.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks for your note and the link.